# invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ c++

Tags: c++

I am getting an error saying "invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’" on line 6. This is my
code:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
   char data[] = "abcdefghi";
   string newData = data[0];
   return 0;
}
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: What exactly is your intent?

Answer (score 3):

The error is because `std::string` does not have a constructor that accepts a single `char` as input, but it does have one that accepts a `const char*`.

You have many different ways to work around this:

```
string newData(data, 1);
```

```
string newData(1, data[0]);
```

```
string newData(data, data+1);
```

```
string newData;
newData += data[0];
```

```
string newData;
newData.push_back(data[0]);
```

```
string newData;
newData.resize(1);
newData[0] = data[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

> string newData = data[0];

This line is creating problem you are assigning a character to a string. Which is saying invalid conversion.
You can do something like this

```
string newData="";
newData+=data[0];
```